# SQL Update Column from another Table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-update

So I have two tables called "MasterTracker" and "CapitalEdge."

I want to update the column "CompanyName" in MasterTracker to equal the table "Target name" in CapitalEdge but only when another column in CapitalEdge, called "Deal Stage" equals "1.0 Prospect"

I know that 44 lines should be updated but I get a popup that says only 32 are being updated.

Also, when I do run the code, nothing actually updates. I am writing this in Microsoft Access if that makes a difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I am running:

```
update MasterTracker
  left 
  join CapitalEdge on CapitalEdge.[Target name] = MasterTracker.[Companyname]
 set MasterTracker.[CompanyName] = CapitalEdge[Target name] 
 where CapitalEdge.[Deal Stage] = "1.0 Prospect";
```

Comment: Incidentally, it's fantastically unlikely that you'd want a LEFT JOIN on an UPDATE clause (with the specific exception of an IS NULL condition). As it happens, the query above is actually an INNER JOIN, so you might as well write it that way to begin with.

Comment: It is not clear how you want to identify the CapitalEdge-Row that should be used to update a Mastertracker-row. Currently, you use the row that already has the same companyname (your join condition), and thus you replace the name with an identical value. It would help if you would add some sample data: some rows for both tables and the expected outcome of your update (e.g. which rows got changed why/got replaced with which value).

Comment: Which is the back end database engine?   SQL Server or Access?

Comment: Access is the back end database design

Comment: Just to emphasize why we need some clarification from you: your current query (and as a result, Dominics answer) goes through your `MasterTracker` table, looks at the value `Companyname` - let's say it is `stackoverflow.com` for some row - looks into the table `CapitalEdge` for a row that has `[Target name] = 'stackoverflow.com'` and the correct value for `Deal Stage` (your join/where), and then replaces `Companyname` by `Target name` - **so with the same value** `stackoverflow.com`! You probably want to do something different, but we do not know what, that's why some examples would help.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have access to test this on, so this code is untested, but raw SQL could be this:

```
update MasterTracker
set CompanyName = CE.[Target Name]
from MasterTracker MT
join CapitalEdge CE on CE.[Target Name] = MT.CompanyName and CE.[Deal Stage] = '1.0 Prospect'
```

Comment: when you say "from MasterTracker MT" do you mean I should type out "from MasterTracker MasterTracker"?

Comment: I am just aliasing MasterTracker to MT to avoid typing MasterTracker again and refer to it by MT... I however agree with above comments that technically this query does not seem to do much in real world since you would update the CompanyName with itself since the join is linking on what is equal already. You would rather be better off having other colums to update or deleting records and inserting the ones that do have 1.0 Prospect in Deal Stage...